# Criar um senha para acessar o Stack overflow sem usar a conta do google

Tags: suporte, login

Quando criei a minha conta no StackOverflow fiz o login pelo Google e não criei uma senha para o login. Agora quero criar um senha para acessar o StackOverflow sem usar a minha conta do Google.

Já tentei de tudo, e não consegui achar essa opção. Como crio uma senha somente para acessar? Não quero usar a minha conta do Google.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voê já clicou lá em `Registre-se` no canto superior direito em azul?

Comment: Sim, mas quando insiro os meus dados, com a senha, retorna a mensagem: "O e-mail utilizado já está registrado". Ou seja, só consigo acessar pela conta do google. Quero criar um conta só para o stack

Comment: Pode tentar remover o *login* da Google em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/81583 mas não sei a consequência disto, não garanto se conseguirá acessar a mesma conta com conta próprio. Eu até acho que sim, mas não me responsabilizo.

Comment: O email que você quer cadastrar é o mesmo que o google usou pra criar sua conta? Se sim, é provável que essa seja a causa do erro. Ai você precisa informar outro email. Depois vincula o novo login ao perfil anterior no link que o @bigown informou e remove o antigo. No perfil tem como trocar de email, caso queira receber notificações no mesmo email atual.

Comment: Eu marquei como duplicada pois a explicação mostra como fazer isso, entretanto agora eu fui tentar e não consegui achar a opção de criar o login do Stack Exchange. Olhando nessa resposta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6172/3117 você pode ver que caso você desassocie a sua conta e fique sem acesso pode entrar com contato com a equipe da comunidade através do https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/contact Mas eu falei com um CM entender qual a melhor opção

Comment: Consegui achar essa tela: https://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true&returnUrl=%2Fusers%2Fcurrent Clica na primeira opção e vê se consegue adicionar o login via StackExchange